# Can't make .container to work properly with Twig/Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I encountered some problems about placing some boxes in a container under Bootstrap.

So here's my code :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            {% for post in posts %}
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    {% include "@CurationBlog/Default/cards/card_default.html.twig" %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

so i'm calling multiple times my *card_default* which only is an article with an image and some body. Here is its code :

```
<div class="ibox">
<div class="ibox-content col-md-12 row-eq-height box-post">
    <div class="col-md-4 img-col">
        <img style="max-height: initial" class="img-responsive" src='{{ post.illustrationUrl }}'>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 border-body" style="background-color: white; padding: 15px;">
        <h3 id="post-title" style="margin-top: 0;">
            <a href="{{ path('curation_blog_redirect_to_post', {'id': post.id}) }}" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" style="color: black;">
                {{ post.title }}
            </a>
        </h3>
        <div class="small m-b-xs">
            <strong>{{ post.author }}</strong> &middot; <span class="text-muted">{{ post.source }}</span>
        </div>
        <p id="description">{{ post.summary }}</p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 'university.body.reading_time'|transchoice(post.readingTimeMinutes) }}</p>
        <div>
            {% for tag in post.tags %}
                <button class="btn btn-white btn-xs" type="button" style="margin-top: 3px;">{{ tag.name }}</button>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Soo i can't find anything wrong in this, but the rendered page looks like this :

[image: rendering of my page]

Yeah images are broken too, but that's an other issue...

If you have any idea, i'm listening !

EDIT : Forgot to precise that my first divs are in good width and height:

[image: enter image description here]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell exactly without seeing this online, but i guess it has something to do with your iboxes having different heights. If you can't manage to apply the same heigth to all of them, try this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    {% for i,post in posts %}
        {% if i%2 == 0 %}<div class="row">{% endif %}
        <div class="col-md-6">
           {% include "@CurationBlog/Default/cards/card_default.html.twig" %}
        </div>
        {% if i%2 == 0 %}</div>{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: I can't have the same height, constraint from work :/

Answer (score 0):

Use this html

You need to use row before using col-* classes again to divide the screen.

```
<div class="ibox">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="ibox-content col-md-12 row-eq-height box-post">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 img-col">
          <img style="max-height: initial" class="img-responsive" src='{{ post.illustrationUrl }}'>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 border-body" style="background-color: white; padding: 15px;">
          <h3 id="post-title" style="margin-top: 0;">
            <a href="{{ path('curation_blog_redirect_to_post', {'id': post.id}) }}" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" style="color: black;">
                  {{ post.title }}
              </a>
          </h3>
          <div class="small m-b-xs">
            <strong>{{ post.author }}</strong> &middot; <span class="text-muted">{{ post.source }}</span>
          </div>
          <p id="description">{{ post.summary }}</p>
          <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 'university.body.reading_time'|transchoice(post.readingTimeMinutes) }}</p>
          <div>
            {% for tag in post.tags %}
            <button class="btn btn-white btn-xs" type="button" style="margin-top: 3px;">{{ tag.name }}</button> {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="ibox">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="ibox-content col-md-12 row-eq-height box-post">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4 img-col">
                <img style="max-height: initial" class="img-responsive" src='data:image/jpeg;base64,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'>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8 border-body" style="background-color: white; padding: 15px;">
                <h3 id="post-title" style="margin-top: 0;">
                  <a href="{{ path('curation_blog_redirect_to_post', {'id': post.id}) }}" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" style="color: black;">
                  {{ post.title }}
              </a>
                </h3>
                <div class="small m-b-xs">
                  <strong>{{ post.author }}</strong> &middot; <span class="text-muted">{{ post.source }}</span>
                </div>
                <p id="description">{{ post.summary }}</p>
                <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 'university.body.reading_time'|transchoice(post.readingTimeMinutes) }}</p>
                <div>
                  {% for tag in post.tags %}
                  <button class="btn btn-white btn-xs" type="button" style="margin-top: 3px;">{{ tag.name }}</button> {% endfor %}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ibox">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="ibox-content col-md-12 row-eq-height box-post">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4 img-col">
                <img style="max-height: initial" class="img-responsive" src='data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBwgHBgkIBwgKCgkLDRYPDQwMDRsUFRAWIB0iIiAdHx8kKDQsJCYxJx8fLT0tMTU3Ojo6Iys/RD84QzQ5OjcBCgoKDQwNGg8PGjclHyU3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3N//AABEIAFoAhwMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAaAAEAAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUH/8QALxAAAgIBAwIDBQkBAAAAAAAAAAECAxEEEkEhURMxYSJUsdHwM1JTcXKBkqLBMv/EABQBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/xAAUEQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD6IAABJBZAAicEpARgnBZInaBTaMGm0bQMsEGm0hoChBZoqwIAAAAAAAA5LopyaRQEpF0iIo0igCiW2l4xz0SOmvR2S6tbV6gcm0jaej4emq882S7cE3JX6bdGKi4PyXYDzHEo0buJnKIGLRnI2kjOaAzAAAAAAAA5NYmXJrEDSJ30aarwVddZ7L4SOGJ6GgasqsofKygOrTypVcp1x2RTxnHUrN02f9XTfpx8DOhY0dqf3vkWojS6W5tZ56+QDw9P+JL6/YvW6K9yVjakuqZzGllE4pYWenX0AmOn09jxGcm8fXB58kehoftn+n5HBPzYGMjGZvIwmBmAAAAAAAByaRM+S6YG0WdGms8K2M+z6/kcsWXiwPauioUXNeUnn4HNpq3bLtFebL0XV26NV2WRjJdOrEYVwWI6zC7Jgb1afZY5N5XBuzj9j33+xHse+v8AkA0kdmqnHsn/AIefJ9T0qvBrtdj1MZNrHVnlSYFZMxmXbM5MCgAAAAAAAHJZFSQLpl4yMiyYGqkWUjFMnIG24ORluG4C7kUbKuRDYEtlJE5KsCAAAAAAAACSABJJUlAWyCpIE5BAAnJGQQAyAQAAAAAAf//Z'>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8 border-body" style="background-color: white; padding: 15px;">
                <h3 id="post-title" style="margin-top: 0;">
                  <a href="{{ path('curation_blog_redirect_to_post', {'id': post.id}) }}" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" style="color: black;">
                  {{ post.title }}
              </a>
                </h3>
                <div class="small m-b-xs">
                  <strong>{{ post.author }}</strong> &middot; <span class="text-muted">{{ post.source }}</span>
                </div>
                <p id="description">{{ post.summary }}</p>
                <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 'university.body.reading_time'|transchoice(post.readingTimeMinutes) }}</p>
                <div>
                  {% for tag in post.tags %}
                  <button class="btn btn-white btn-xs" type="button" style="margin-top: 3px;">{{ tag.name }}</button> {% endfor %}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ibox">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="ibox-content col-md-12 row-eq-height box-post">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4 img-col">
                <img style="max-height: initial" class="img-responsive" src='data:image/jpeg;base64,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'>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8 border-body" style="background-color: white; padding: 15px;">
                <h3 id="post-title" style="margin-top: 0;">
                  <a href="{{ path('curation_blog_redirect_to_post', {'id': post.id}) }}" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" style="color: black;">
                  {{ post.title }}
              </a>
                </h3>
                <div class="small m-b-xs">
                  <strong>{{ post.author }}</strong> &middot; <span class="text-muted">{{ post.source }}</span>
                </div>
                <p id="description">{{ post.summary }}</p>
                <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 'university.body.reading_time'|transchoice(post.readingTimeMinutes) }}</p>
                <div>
                  {% for tag in post.tags %}
                  <button class="btn btn-white btn-xs" type="button" style="margin-top: 3px;">{{ tag.name }}</button> {% endfor %}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if i add a row after .ibox-content, my images are now cropped and it doesn't look like it change anything

Comment: Works fine for me. Added a snippet, will add with image in some time

Comment: Also i had added  2 rows. 1 after .ibox_content and 1 after .ibox

Comment: Which bootstrap are you using? Try using bootstrap 4 if possible.

Comment: Or try adding this style .row { display: flex;     flex-wrap: wrap;}